# connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.27]:2060: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2

I am running in web server on EC2 instance.

My domain is registered on google

Using Postfix to send mail.

Every time i request to send mail this error pop-up:

connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.27]:2060: Connection timed out

Please help

Comment: Does your instance has access to the internet? Are there any firewalls on it NACLs on your subnet blocking email ports?

Comment: Yes, By default  AWS EC2 blocks Port 25, so i have change default smtp port to 2060.  But this is not working so.

Comment: Is 2060 documented as an alternate MSA port for Google SMTP?  You can't simply make up a port number, and Google already supports port 587... so it isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ya ... i got your point.. EC2 was blocking Port 25, I have made request for unblocking and it is approved. All fine. sending mail from port 25